# I have 2 or more instances starting with an identical name, I want to run terraform script for all those

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

```
resource "google_compute_instance_iam_binding" "vm-access" {
  project = var.project_id
  instance_name=
  role    = "roles/compute.osLogin"
  members = ["group", ]
  condition {
    title       = "vm-access"
    description = "allows read-only access to fmis instances only"
    expression  = "resource.type == \"compute.googleapis.com/Instance\" && resource.name.startsWith(\"instance\")"
  }
}
```

I want that instance_name to be filled in such a way that, I can apply this to all vms starting with the name instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for_each to apply this to all VM.

Details available to below link

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each